# How to change source of image in magento

Tags: magento

Please tell me how to change the image source in magento dynamically.say I want that after every 10 seconds I want to change the source of image.
now I have define a static block which contain image src with id banner..
now my question is where should I define for changing the image source and how to change the source.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into a jQuery based image rotator. There are some simple examples out there such as this one:

http://burnmind.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-automatic-image-rotator-using-jquery

Also be careful not to cause conflicts with jQuery and Prototype. You can use [this method](http://www.pauldonnelly.net/jquery-conflict-with-prototype-in-magento/) to avoid this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these links: They are free extensions which may serve your purpose.

http://expertmagentodevelopers.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/download-magento-banner-slider-extensions-free/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/banner-slider-3912.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Interakting.com/extension/2255/interakting-slider#overview